# Booking in specified time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a part of my table which contains

```
Post_time              Post_date     
------------------------------------
06:13:15.0000000       2015-07-15    
22:13:15.0000000       2015-07-15
03:13:15.0000000       2015-07-16
..........             ..........
..........             ..........
```

I need to get all the the infos WHERE time stamp between 22:00 and 05:00 in the next day.So that's mean the Post date is changed , it is another day. and I need that for all the table not only this date.

I tried this :

```
SELECT Post_time FROM dbo.My_Table WHERE
Post_time between dateadd(HH,22,cast(cast(Post_date as date) as datetime))    and
 dateadd(HH,29,cast(cast(Post_date as date) as datetime))
```

but i got this :

```
The data types time and date are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT Post_time FROM dbo.My_Table WHERE
Post_date+Post_time between dateadd(HH,22,cast(cast(Post_date as date) as datetime))    and
 dateadd(HH,29,cast(cast(Post_date as date) as datetime))
```

or casting Post_Time

```
SELECT Post_time FROM dbo.My_Table WHERE
Post_date+cast(Post_time as datetime) between dateadd(HH,22,cast(cast(Post_date as date) as datetime))    and
 dateadd(HH,29,cast(cast(Post_date as date) as datetime))
```

Actually if you are only checking the time, you don't need Post_date

```
   SELECT Post_time 
     FROM dbo.My_Table 
    WHERE
    CAST('2001-01-01' as datetime) + CAST(Post_time AS datetime) 
    between cast('2001-01-01 22:00' AS datetime) AND
    between cast('2001-01-02 05:00' AS datetime)
```

Comment: The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: @Chis try the last one.

Comment: @Chis:You have to replace your table  :)